# Call Number plugin issue

Tags: ionic3

I am using call number plugin for my phone call functionality. But, every time i try to make any call i am getting below error:
Call Number Error:: CouldNotCallPhoneNumber

I have imported and declared CallNumber module in my app.module.ts and file where it is used also.

```
dial(postJson) {
try {
  let self = this;
  self.callNumber.callNumber(postJson.contactNumber, true).then(success => {
    console.log("Call Number Success::", success);
    self.logCall(postJson);
    self.saveDisabled = false
    self.dialDisabled = false
    self.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage')
  },
    error => {
      self.saveDisabled = false
      self.dialDisabled = false
      let validContact = "", enterValidContact = "", ok: any = "";
      self.translate.get('validContact').subscribe((res: string) => { validContact = res; });
      self.translate.get('enterValidContact').subscribe((res: string) => { enterValidContact = res; });
      console.log("Call Number Error::", error);
      let alert = self.alertCtrl.create({
        title: validContact,
        message: enterValidContact,
        buttons: ['Ok']
      });
      alert.present();
    });
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Error in Dial::", e)
}
```

}

is my dial function code .

postJson is :
contactName: "Jgugugugug"
contactNumber: "7206404214"
purposeOfCall: "Follow Up"
product: "Reksadana/MutualFund"
callDate: Mon Jan 20 2020 12:46:37 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
**proto**: Object

```
  **app.module.ts**

    import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';

    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    // HomePage,
    contactSupportPage,
  ],

  imports: [
    // AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    // AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    // AngularFireAuthModule,
    FormsModule,
    Ng2HighchartsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    PdfViewerModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DirectiveModule,
    ImgFallbackModule,//for fallback images if the url fails to load or url is broken,
    ComponentModule,
    PipeModule,
    ProviderModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      prodMode: true,
      tabsHideOnSubPages: true,
      mode: 'ios',
      scrollAssist: false,
      autoFocusAssist: false,
      backButtonText: ''
    }),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    // HomePage,
    contactSupportPage,
  ],
  providers: [
    CallNumber
  ],
  //AppProviders.getProvider(),
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
// App Module File
```

Comment: can you post full code of the module.ts ?

Comment: @khanh Le Tran please find the same.

Comment: oh my bad @@ sorry , i need component.ts

Comment: @KhanhLeTran can you please tell me why component.ts is needed. I haven't used CallNumber in that file